# How do I import an html file into another?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that is in three of my website's files. I would like to put this bar (with css and all) in a separate file to import to these, as to make it so I wouldn't have to go through and edit all three navigation bars when I want to make a change. Is there a way to do this in Brackets?

Comment: Are you open to using PHP for that? You don't have to code your whole site in PHP (except for one small php_inlcude line) but you just need to rename the file extension of your HTML files.

Comment: If you're doing pure HTML/CSS, there's no way of doing this.  You will need to use a language like php or angular to do something like this.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem, He can only do this if he's running on a server that supports PHP.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Agreed. Most linux hosting servers online support PHP though hence why I recommended this solution.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I agree, though since he's using brackets (and the complexity of his question), I assume he's writing local HTML.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Good point.

Comment: you can also do it with jquery, but not with just html: $(function () { $("#your-div").load("your-html-include.html"); });

Answer (score 0):

If you are not 100% married to the files being .html, you could make your files .php and include your html by using `<?php include "path/to.php"; ?>`

Comment: running PHP on the server is required. And contray to what most PHP developers think, there are a lot of servers (and localhosts) who do not run PHP

Comment: What @martin said is totally right.  You will need to check with your host that you can run PHP on your server.